# Splitting Blender animation into separate clips

Tags: animation, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, unity

I am new to Blender and working on a uni project with a very close deadline and really really in need to help. I've created an animated character in blender that I am importing into Unity.

The character has a rigged hair mesh and a rigged dress mesh parented to the rigged body.   (See screenshot) [image: Screenshot of rigged character - three separate rigs - one for hair one for dress and one for body]

I was unaware of the action editor when i started so, I used the dopesheet to create a run cycle and a jump animation all in one animation clip. I then animated the hair and dress to they move with the running body. I need to import this into unity but am having huge issues and was wondering if someone could help:

1. Is there anyway I can merge all the animation for the hair, dress an body together into one animation clip. That way I would have, One animation clip for the run and one animation clip for the jump.

   2. If not how do I split the animations that I have all in one animation clip, into separate animation clips. So that I can have - character_runcycle, character_jump, hair_runcycle, hair_run, hair_jump. But then I have no idea how I would set this up in Unity.

Can someone please please help?

I tried using the F button to create new animation clips but I couldn't separate out the hair from the dress animations even though in the animation timeline the keyframes were only for the hair. I'm so completely confused, this is all very new to me and i am working to a VERY tight deadline for my uni project deadline so any advice is needed and much appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance! xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to create a new action

1. Press the F-Button so it is darkened to keep your existing action in the blend file even when you save and reload it. Otherwise you might loose your animation. So in case you're uncertain make a backup copy.
2. Press the [image] button to unlink the action.
3. Press the New button to create a new action.

### Copy frames from one action to another

- Switch between your actions by pressing the [image: Action Dropdown Menu] button and choose your desired action from the dropdown menu
- Select a frame range by pressing the <kbd>B</kbd> key to activate the border select and select a range of frames in the dopesheet editor.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or press the [image: Copy] button in the header menu to copy frames to a clipboard
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or press the [image: Paste] button in the header menu to paste the frames at the current cursor location (green line)